# How to specify bearing clearance fit for fabrication shop

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, bearings

I have a bearing with outer diameter 100mm and inner diameter 55mm. The bearing sits on top of housing unit A, and housing unit B sits on top of the bearing. Diameter d1 fits with the bearing's inner diameter and diameter d2 fits with the bearing's outer diameter. Housing B applies rotation on Housing A, so the bearing's inner ring will rotate but outer ring will be stationary. My questions were:

1. I wanted to have a transition fit for the outer ring and a clearance fit for the inner ring. What should the diameters of d1 and d2 be then in my mechanical drawing?
2. The fabrication shop I am sending to get the parts made states that their standard machining tolerance is +/- 0.005 in. (0.13mm) with some higher end equipment with machining tolerance of +/-0.002 in. (0.051 mm). So does that mean I can only achieve a clearance fit?
3. Would the diameters of the housing rings change if I want to use aluminum vs low carbon steel for housings A and B? The bearing's ring material is steel.
   [image]

Comment: 5 thousandths seems really high to me, they're covering their butt.  But this is different than your interference spec, which should come from the bearing manufacturer.

Comment: Those machining tolerances are pretty poor. Even at home on my ML7 2 thou was easily achievable, 1 thou required some effort but was not difficult. I don't know what the 5 thou machine would be, fit for the scrapheap is one idea. Your bearing manufacturers handbook will tell you what you need to know.

Comment: This is the bearing: https://www.mcmaster.com/5972K113/ . It says clearance fit needs to be 0.023mm to 0.043mm. Does that mean d1 diameter should be 54.997mm to 54.957mm?

Comment: I don't believe 0.005" is what their machines are capable of. I was able to hit that the first time I touched a lathe or boring tool. Maybe they just don't care to spend any more time setting up their machines to achieve anything better (i.e. no trial runs to tune or dial things in). Scrap heap indeed.

Comment: Books and tables about limits and fits. Check out Geick and Zeus.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the data. The  0.023 to 0.043mm is the internal clearance within the bearing. How much clearance there is between the ball and the race. If you look a few lines up you'll see "shaft mount press fit". This means you want an *interference fit* on the shaft. Not a clearance fit

Comment: @DanielK I see now, thanks